# How to exit out of a remote server when jenkins user invokes a script

Tags: java, bash, jenkins

I am trying to implement a continuous deployment pipeline with jenkins and i have two servers namely:

1. Jenkins server
2. remote server where i am running my application

I have managed to send an artifact from the jenkins server to the remote server. I also created a script on the remote server to run the artifact once its on the remote server.

> My problem is when i check the console log of the jenkins branch which is being built i see the logs for the jar running on the remote server. How do i exit out of the other server once i start the .sh file on the remote server.

Here is my script for the remote server.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# syntax to specify which command to monitor
scp -P 22 /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/test/eureka-naming-server/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/eureka-naming-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar myname@myServer:/home/test/repository/eureka-service-deploy

ssh -p 22 myname@myServer '/home/test/ubuntu/server/start.sh &'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i just needed to add > /dev/null 2>&1 & at the end of the ssh command so that it looks like this :

```
> ssh -p 22 myname@myServer '/home/test/ubuntu/server/start.sh >
> /dev/null 2>&1 &'
```

This blog gives more information about how to setup jenkins and enable continuous delivery

[Link to blog](http://smasue.github.io/fat-jar-deployment-bamboo)